# MVVMCross MvxDatePicker Binding in Android AXML

Tags: android, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a DatePicker in axml that looks like this

```
<MvxDatePicker
      ...
      local:MvxBind="DateTime CustomReminderDate"
      android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

This binds correctly to the ViewModel and displays the right value, BUT when a new Date is chosen using the spinner the new Date is not getting set in the ViewModel bound property.

Any idea what am I missing?

Notes: I am using Xamarin and this is on Android

Comment: I think you may have forgot to post some code.  Hard to tell what is happening with out that.

Comment: Here's one that works - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Droid/Resources/Layout/Test_Date.axml (ViewModel in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Core/ViewModels/ViewModels.cs#L67)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to the "Value" property instead of the "DateTime" property.

```
<MvxDatePicker
      ...
      local:MvxBind="Value CustomReminderDate"
      android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

Though these properties yield the same underlying DateTime value, the "DateTime" property is declared on the native Android DatePicker while the "Value" Property is declared on the MvvmCross ancestor, MvxDatePicker, and is designed for binding.